# Weighted inaccuracy of forecasts

Tags: probability, forecasting, accuracy, scoring-rules

Suppose we have two random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, where $X_1 = 1$ if there's a tornado, $X_2 = 1$ if there's an earthquake. Let

$$\cal X = \{ \mathbf x = \langle \mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2 \rangle : \mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2 \in \{0,1\}\},$$ with $X_i(\mathbf x) = 1$ iff $\mathbf x_i=1$.

Any probability function defined over the Boolean closure of $\cal X$ corresponds to a prediction of the values of our two random variables.

We can measure the inaccuracy of a probability function $P$ relative to a given outcome $\mathbf x$ using the mean squared error, or Brier score:

$$BS(P,\mathbf x) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{\mathbf y \in \cal X} (P(\mathbf y) - \mathbb 1_{\mathbf x = \mathbf y})^2,$$

where $\mathbb 1_{\mathbf x = \mathbf y}$ is 1 if $\mathbf x = \mathbf y$ and 0 otherwise.

Consider now the following two probability functions:

$P(\langle 1,0 \rangle) = 0.1,$
$P(\langle 1,1 \rangle) = 0.1,$
$P(\langle 0,0 \rangle) = 0.1,$
$P(\langle 0,1 \rangle) = 0.7.$

$Q(\langle 1,0 \rangle) = 0.1,$
$Q(\langle 1,1 \rangle) = 0.1,$
$Q(\langle 0,0 \rangle) = 0.7,$
$Q(\langle 0,1 \rangle) = 0.1.$

$P$ and $Q$ are equally inaccurate relative to $\langle 1,0\rangle$. But it seems reasonable to favor $P$ over $Q$ as a prediction: it gave a reasonably accurate prediction about whether there would be a natural disaster.

What I'm after is some weighted inaccuracy measure that will treat $P$ and $Q$ differently. More generally, I'm after a measure of weighted inaccuracy with the following property: if the inaccuracy of $P$ and $Q$ are the same (with respect to a given state $\mathbf x$), the weighted inaccuracy of $P$ will be greater than that of $Q$ iff $P$ is less accurate than $Q$ about whether a natural disaster occurs in $\mathbf x$.

We could start by appealing to the analog of weighted Euclidean distance. We could define a weight function $w$ that assigns a real number to each $\mathbf x \in \cal X$ and set

$$BS_w(P,\mathbf x) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{\cal X} w(\mathbf y)(P(\mathbf y) - \mathbb 1_{\mathbf x = \mathbf y})^2.$$

Let $D = \cal X \setminus \{ \langle 0, 0 \rangle \}$ -- think of $D$ as the 'natural disaster' event. What I need is a weight function $w$ with the following property: if $BS(P, \mathbf x) = BS(Q, \mathbf x)$, then $BS_w(P, \mathbf x) < BS_w(Q,\mathbf x)$ iff $P(s)$ is closer to $\chi_D(\mathbf x)$, where $\chi_D$ is the characteristic function of $D$.

Initially I thought that as long as $w(\mathbf x) > w(\mathbf y)$ if $\mathbf y \not \in \cal X$, I could secure the desired result. But I'm unable to prove that this is so, nor to find a counterexample.